# GeoServer Maven Quickstart fails during build process

Tags: geoserver, maven

I am trying to build GeoServer using Maven. I followed the instructions from the GeoServer  website [Instruction from GeoServer site](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/developer/quickstart/maven.html). When i get to the build stage it fails. I have tried to search for cases where this happened but not been able to find any solutions.
In the error reads Invalid escape character at line 1...... attached is a screen shot of the error.

[image: Error message]

I am using Windows 10, apache-maven3.6.0 bin. Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: Pretty much all the GeoServer devs use a unix system for development so not much chance of any help I'm afraid. However the build is tested using AppVeyor so it should work.

Comment: I could try in a virtual environment to see if it would work.. So far i have tried different approaches and i have not been successful I was also wondering maybe it might be the version of maven.

Comment: Please do not provide pictures of errors, which are neither legible on all devices nor searchable; instead include the actual text as ASCII in the body of the question.

Comment: I'm currently using mvn 3.6.0 and Java 1.8.0_191 are what I'm currently using

Comment: Looking at the error, it seems more of a file encoding issue. How did you get the sources? If it's git, I'd check its checkout options.